# Are WSL related questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Today i have voted close this question: [Does Microsoft WLinux has full support for network and devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/487534/34720)

Using the same logic as the [Cygwin related questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/436/34720), shall we mark all stuff related to WSL as off-topic, since even inside that Linux container a Windows product limitation could be the root cause of a problem, or only the ones that are clearly inside the list of features/limitations of this Microsoft product?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm afraid we've already decided it's on topic and even had [a nice discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4226/22222) about what tag to use. And, admittedly, that's the right call. While it is running in a Windows environment, it really is a <del>Linux system</del> "Linux-like environment" as far as I can tell. By the way, Cygwin is also on topic, that's been decided in the very question you linked to.

So, as you say, by the same logic WSL is also on topic. That said, I migrated that question over to SU since I am assuming more people with WSL experience hang out there than here.

Comment: Nice. Answered that, as this kind of topic is all about the will of Microsoft to implement something, and the will of the user to navigate inside the WSL github and check if it's working :) - https://superuser.com/a/1382953/210242

Comment: @nwildner I'm glad you answered. I migrated since I felt it had a better chance of being answered there, but in general, I think people using the standard tools on WSL can ask here.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "a Linux system", but a "Linux-like environment" (much like Cygwin). AFAIK, there is no Linux kernel, and there are Linux-related kernel-related _things_ missing.

Comment: WSL version 2 has the Linux kernel, but some things are *still* missing or need workarounds to work the same as on a Linux system.