# Do we need to git a new tag for Git Bash questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm seeing some questions lately pertaining to ["git bash"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22git+bash%22) or ["gitbash"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=gitbash) and had to go look to see if this was something different from [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux), and it seems that it **is** different. I learned more about it from an [Atlassian Git bash tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash) and the [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) page. It's summarized as:

> Git Bash is a package that installs Bash, some common bash utilities, and Git on a Windows operating system.

and:

> Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line.

... respectively.

Assuming we consider them on-topic ([previously: Cygwin](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/cygwin-on-topic) and [previously: WSL](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/are-wsl-related-questions-off-topic)), is there a need for a new tag? If so, what should it be called, and what should the excerpt & wiki say about it?

Comment: (The "git" in the title being an intentional ["dialectal variant of 'get'"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/git)).

Comment: I wonder if the shell and tools are in any way _different_ from, say, the ordinary `bash` shell and GNU toolset? If so, it may make sense to have a separate tag. It may also be a reason to have a separate `gitbash` tag if there is something _else_ peculiar about the actual environment that "Git Bash" gives you that means that running everyday user tasks would be different from doing them on any other GNU system. WSL is different from this in that it's a "complete system" (AFAIK) with packages and whatnot, as is Cygwin.

Comment: The differences b/w native and this version are discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034549/difference-between-git-gui-git-bash-git-cmd

Answer (score 3):

I think we don't. Git Bash is just [a redistribution of MSYS2/MinGW](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/The-difference-between-MINGW-and-MSYS2#git-for-windows-2x-mingw-and-msys2). We already have tags for those, so we should just make a synonym for one of these. I suggest [msys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msys), since that's where the tools come from. I'd imagine that the non-MSYS, non-git-cli parts of Git Bash would be off-topic here.

Comment: Will the users who ask about this topic be familiar with the term "msys"? Is it a commonly used term?

Comment: @terdon not sure about that. It's like Ubuntu and Linux a bit - people might have heard of Ubuntu but have no idea what a Linux is. But inasmuch as any peculiarities of the platform necessitate the use of a tag, msys is the platform. A synonym should be enough, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the first thing about any of these either. I'm just thinking we should make sure the tag name is something the average user would think of. And, since I don't know anything about this thing, I can't judge what that would be :)

Comment: @terdon isn’t the whole point of synonyms that users can use them without thinking too much, and questions will still be categorised appropriately? This case is somewhat complicated because it’s the same underlying technology, but Git Bash users are largely unaware they’re using MSYS.