# Can questions about Windows subsystem for linux be asked here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am thinking about asking Linux questions that run with Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL). Can I ask questions that can apply to WSL and the "raw" distro?

Comment: Yes; see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/437/117549 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4226/117549