# Can we have a [wsl]->[windows-subsystem-for-linux] synonym?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678478/cant-move-or-rename-folder-in-git-repo-permission-denied-despite-being-drwxr?noredirect=1#comment1281523_678478), aliasing [wsl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wsl) would make sense.

Should and could someone with enough reputation make that alias?

Comment: Relating https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4226/117549

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've [proposed the wsl alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/synonyms) for the [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) tag. Looks like there's only [13 users that qualify](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/topusers) for voting on the alias at the moment (myself *not* included), so we'll need to get lucky or be patient :)

Comment: It's got a score of 2 (out of 4) right now.

Comment: we might want to improve that amount of potential voters by making sure questions are tagged, but that's something we should do for new questions anyway.

Comment: Can't mods create synonyms without going through the voting process?

Comment: @muru is there a need for haste?

Comment: @Kusalananda realistically, how fast do tag synonyms get created? I'm thinking somewhere on around "never", since we need an intersection of people (a) that have the voting rights, (b) either know a synonym has been proposed or go to the tag page and find out and (c) actually do that voting too.

Comment: I was considering featuring this post as a way to get more main-site visibility. I hesitate to mod-vote on an alias, since I don't want to speak for the community. If the natural voting doesn't get there, I'd consider "enough" positive voting on these posts (and lack of opposition) to be an indication that the community thinks it's a good idea, and hammer the alias in.

Comment: I'd vote for it if i could, because i think the synonym is a good idea - even though I've never answered a WSL-only question and probably never will (unless it's also tagged with, or about, bash or sed or awk or something).

Comment: 3 out of 4 as of today

Comment: Incidentally, [the list of proposed synonyms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) is a handy page to visit every once in a while. See also [Some kind of notification system for when tag synonyms are suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304152/285232) and the linked questions.

Comment: What happened with this? It doesn't seem to be an option you can vote on anymore, it doesn't exist as a synonym, and there are no pending tag synonyms at this moment for the community. I'd like to look at this another way: what will be the downsides of including this synonym? The only one I could think of is if there was something else that stood for wsl. If you Google "wsl," the first page refers to either "wsl" or "World Surf League." Because of the former, in our domain, I think this acronym is ubiquitous.

Comment: @DanielKaplan the [wsl synonym is currently at 3 votes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested); there's not a very long list of qualified voters, so if there's no objections (and I haven't seen any), I'd be willing to push this through.

Comment: @JeffSchaller do I not have enough permissions to see that? https://i.ibb.co/py8jRNP/image.png

Comment: Sorry; I wonder why! Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/synonyms instead? That's the one specifically for the "wsl" tag and shows the proposed synonym.

Comment: @JeffSchaller interesting. Could that be a site bug? I can see your latest link. My vote would be to push that through. Thanks.

Comment: If I was to guess, it's got a reputation filter, perhaps at the 2500 "create synonyms" level. When I saw it posted by Stephen, I assumed (!) that it was wide open.